# To find dimension of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let V be subspace of $M_n (R) $ be subspace ofall matrices such that entries in every row add upto zero and entries in every columm also add upto zero .Then i am to find its dimension . I have tried simplematrices but coudnot get to correct answer.Thanks

Comment: You want to find the dimension of the subspace containing all those $n \times n$ matrices. Think of each matrix as a very long vector with $n^{2}$ entries. How many linear constraints do you put on its entries? For example, the requirement that the sum of the first row is equal to $0$, can be written as one linear constraint. How many of them are linearly independent?

Comment: @m.a. i didnot completely understood you .

Comment: Can you please elaborate more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $\times $ is used for a known value: for example given all the components of the first row then the last component is 
$$a_{1n}=-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{1k}$$ so a matrix in the mentioned subspace takes the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&\cdots&\cdots& \times\\ \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\\times&\times&\cdots&\times\end{pmatrix}$$
hence we see that the dimension of the subspace is the number of unknown components: $$n^2-(2n-1)=(n-1)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Without your assumptions you have $n^2$ parameters, but now, for example, last row and last column is determined. How many parameters remain?

Comment: Can you Please elaborate